# fast spherical filter: interpolation

Tags: dft, interpolation

Here is the minimum working examples of fast spherical filter in

[c++](https://pastebin.com/99ZACHC9)

The reference paper is [Fast Spherical Filter](http://cmst.curtin.edu.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2020/04/Wilkes2017.pdf)

There is a bug in the implementation where the `computed_grid` values does not match with `filtered_grid` values.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I haven’t ran the code. What’s the bug? An error message? Or an output you don’t expect? If it’s the latter, what do you get and what do you expect? If it’s the former, what’s the error message?

Comment: There are no compilation error. In the input function ```lg=9``` and ```lt=17``` are the sample lengths of N-S and E-S direction. In the interpolation function ```lg=12``` and ```lt=23```. Bug is interpolated values are wrong.

Comment: I was kind of double minded whether to post the code but in the end I did it. Please don't close the question, which has happened last time :-(

Comment: It'd help if you (a) provide compilable code (as a link to pastebin or something); (b) provide compilation instructions; (c) most importantly: specify a program input, what you expect the output to be, and what the output is; (d) provide the minimum amount of code that reproduces the problem. Even then, consider posting this in a software-related SE site.

Comment: compilable code is bit difficult since it depends on Eigen and GSL. In the attached paper there are four equations and here I got four separate nested loop.

Comment: I understand it's not so clear. If there are no answers mods can delete it.

Comment: It might help us (and you) if you first tried this with a scripting language such as python or matlab. A lot easier for quick debugging / visualizing

Comment: From the variable names, it may be clear what each nested loop does. I critically miss one thing to understand hence my interpolated values does not match with computed values.

Comment: A bit more readable now.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the bug. Need to set the order correctly.